# Why is my label cutting off on the middle? WPF C# .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, label

So just recently when i started messing around with that blue bar thing (demo in the picture)
It started cutting off the labels for some weird reason.
In this picture you can see that it says 
OS: Win 
 Available RAM
 etc but it should say Windows 8.1 and Available ram "And the exact number"
I DO NOT have any stack panels or anything covering it im suspecting that it has something to do with the blue bar (Picture 2)

 im new to WPF.

[image]

[image]

PICTURE 2 ^

As you can see there is a blue bar next to the labels and Im starting to suspect hat it tis the one messing things up.
What is causing my labels to cut off?

```
<Page x:Class="TestApplication.systemPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplication"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Background="White"
      d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="525"
      Title="systemPage">


    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Name="Stacky" Background="#03a3d2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Margin="-262,-59,0,-59" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
        <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="84" Margin="160,13,-260,-97" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Images/Logo.png" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="osInfo" Content="OS:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,-42,-47,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="28" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="ramInfo" Content="Available RAM:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,-21,-108,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="89" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="systemHealth" Content="System Diagnose:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,72,-123,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="104" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="cpuInfo" Content="CPU:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,0,-54,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="CPUUsage" Content="N/A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,0,-85,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="31" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="RAMUsage" Content="N/A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,-21,-139,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" Width="31"/>
        <Label x:Name="osInfoLabel" Content="N/A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,-42,-78,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="31" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="startScanButton" Click="startScanButton_Click" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Content="Start Diagnose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-143,29,0,-61" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="137" Height="32" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="connectionStateLabel" Content="N/A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,22,-108,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="31" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="networkLabel" Content="Network:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,22,-77,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="58" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="diagnoseResultLabel" Content="N/A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,72,-154,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" Width="31"/>



    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You are setting a specific width on your labels and it is keeping them from growing horizontally. Also as @EdPlunkett said the margins are probably an issue.

Comment: I think you should first maybe back this up, get rid of all the weird margins and fixed heights and widths the designer puked all over the place, and do the layout using StackPanels and alignments.

Answer (score 1):

It's getting cut off because you dragged and dropped controls onto the form rather then hand coded the XAML. If you want it dynamic, you need to hand craft the XAML with the proper layout panels (Grid, StackPanel, etc) using proper layout techniques. The designer produced code is not dynamic at all. It's very strict.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting cut off because you have fixed width on most of the controls. for example,

`<Label x:Name="diagnoseResultLabel" Content="N/A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,72,-154,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" Width="31"/>`

Get rid of `Width` property (or make it `Auto`) and it would work. At the same time as @SledgeHammer pointed out, please craft the XAML with with some layouts.

Comment: Just letting people know that, it didnt work, still the same thing.

Comment: @JohnM.Henreick Did you try removing ``Width="0*"`` ? I believe that is the only thing left in your case messing up with the layout.

Comment: yeah I did, I also tried making it auto. Posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**What worked for me**

I deleted this part from my XAMl

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Not sure what it did but im assuming it deleted some transparent wall that was infront of it.

Comment: there is no magic in it. You just made a plain grid with only one row and one column and that's what I referred to you in my answer to do. Remove ``Width`` from grid column definitions.